# Why hundreds of images have disappeared from my Upload folder?

Tags: wordpress, image, host

I had a website on OVH host, everything was working fine.

An image file named https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/htilominlo-1-1118x745.jpeg was showing the image on front, and was in the upload folder.

I decided to change the host. I'm now on o2switch. They made the transfert of the entire website.

Now the process is finished, but there are hundreds of images missing on front, like the one above, and they are not anymore in the upload folder.

Can someone tell me what could be the reason ?

The website files and folders are still on the old ovh host, I can see them through ftp filezila. But the missing images on front are not anymore in the upload folders....mystery..

Comment: Have you changed the root path? In your original SQL file, the `/home/` path might be different.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, rename the uploads folder to uploadsbck on your new host. Secondly, copy the uploads folder of previous host where there were all the images and copy the upload folder to new host. And on completions change the permalink from backend > settings > permalink.

Comment: yes thank you for your help. It's an issue with ovh, i don't know how but images disappeared from my upoads folder in my wordpress site. i have a backup so normally it's ok! thanks

Comment: The media folder was too enormous, with thousands of images, and some files were thus hidden in the ftp client side. When transfering all the images, due to the weight of the folder, some of them were not transfered. Finaly O2switch solved the problem.They went over it several times and finally managed to import everything !!